# Is it safe to use a loop variable within a nested script, even without SETLOCAL

Tags: windows, batch-file

Suppose a `CALL` appears within a `FOR` loop.  Is it safe to use the variable that controls the loop within the second script, even if the second script does not `SETLOCAL`?  Something like this:

```
FOR %%A IN (A B C) DO (
ECHO %%A
CALL Second.bat
)
```

```
REM This is Second.bat
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) DO (
ECHO %%A
...
)
```

In my tests, variable `A` seems local to each script.  I would like to know whether this behavior is granted.

Comment: If you need a variable passed into another script then do so. `CALL Second.bat "%%A"`. Then reference that argument as `%1` in Second.bat.

Comment: That's right.  However, I would like to know whether I can choose loop variables without worrying about name collisions between batch files.

Comment: Doesn't your code output prove to you that there is no collision.  Sure seems like it to me.  You certainly can't echo %%A before the `FOR` command in second.bat.

Comment: Second `FOR` changes de variable.  I want to be sure this does not affect first `FOR`.  My tests in my machine show that there is no collision, but my scripts will run elsewhere.

Comment: Does this clear it up for you. `for %%A in (A B C) DO FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) do echo %%A`

Comment: you say, second `for` changes the variable, there is no variable, just metavariables created at the time it executes each item. while the metavariable is active during the execution of the for loop, it is valid until re-assigned to the next item in the for loop OR if you re-assign it elsewhere (second `for` loop), but we can return and reuse it (First `for` loop). `@for %%A in (A B C) DO echo %%A & FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) do @echo %%A` even in this example the result can be demonstrated. `FOR %A IN (1 2 3)`

Comment: it can be demonstrated even in a third loop `@for %%A in (A B C) DO echo %%A & FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) do @echo %%A & FOR %%A IN (X Y Z) do @echo %%A` however is it a good idea? Not at all. Once the metavariable is re-assigned, you can no longer use it.

Comment: I do not want to use the reassigned variable.  I want not to damage the first loop.

Comment: no variable is re-assigned, it is active while in use, but it is still not a good idea, just use another metavariable identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question:
Yes, it is safe to use the same `for` loop meta-variable in a called script without `setlocal`/`endlocal`, because such are not related to the environment block, which merely contains environment variables (those usually assigned by `set`) as well as the current working directory.

When multiple nested loops use the same meta-variable, the inner-most loop defines the returned value. As soon as the inner-most loop is finished, the loop of the next higher nesting level defines the return value, and so on. So meta-variables are never overwritten, they are local to each individual loop.

---

The following scripts demonstrate that there is no relation between meta-variables and the environment block, and that meta-variables do even not depend on whether they appear in the main or a called sub script:

1. This script just contains two nested `for` loops (the outer one iterates once only, establishing two meta-variables `%%A` and `%%B`; the inner one iterates twice, reestablishing meta-variable `%%A`):

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("outer_A outer_B") do (
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
        endlocal
        for %%A in (inner_1 inner_2) do (
            echo Inner loop: "%%A" "%%B"
        )
        setlocal
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
    )
    echo End
    endlocal
    exit /B
   ```
2. This time the inner `for` loop is moved into a called sub-routine:

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("outer_A outer_B") do (
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
        endlocal
        call :SUB
        setlocal
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
    )
    echo End
    endlocal
    exit /B

    :SUB
    for %%A in (inner_1 inner_2) do (
        echo Inner loop: "%%A" "%%B"
    )
   ```
3. This time the inner `for` loop is moved into a called sub-script:

   ```
    @echo off
    setlocal
    for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("outer_A outer_B") do (
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
        endlocal
        call "sub.bat"
        setlocal
        echo Outer loop: "%%A" "%%B"
    )
    echo End
    endlocal
    exit /B
   ```

   This is the sub-script `sub.bat`:

   ```
    @echo off
    for %%A in (inner_1 inner_2) do (
        echo Inner loop: "%%A" "%%B"
    )
   ```

Each of the above scripts return exactly the same output:

> ```
> Outer loop: "outer_A" "outer_B"
> Inner loop: "inner_1" "outer_B"
> Inner loop: "inner_2" "outer_B"
> Outer loop: "outer_A" "outer_B"
> End
> ```

This proves that the `for` meta-variables are not related to the environment block, because they are still available after `endlocal` when the loop was initialised after `setlocal`. Furthermore, it proves that meta-variables can be accessed when they are initialised in another section of a script or even in another script.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `second.bat` inherits the state of the parent script's environment block. Loop variables are not stored in the environment block, they are limited to loop block scope. You can even nest them:

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions

@for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do @(
    @echo OuterA: %%A
    @for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do @echo %%InnerA: %%A
)
```

Outputs:

```
> test
OuterA: 1
%InnerA: 1
%InnerA: 2
%InnerA: 3
OuterA: 2
%InnerA: 1
%InnerA: 2
%InnerA: 3
OuterA: 3
%InnerA: 1
%InnerA: 2
%InnerA: 3
```

While it's okay to use the same loop variable in sequential loops, it should be avoided in nested loops, as it can cause some confusion for maintainers/reviewers. In your case, it's perfectly safe and acceptable to use the same control variable names in your loops.

Comment: My loops are nested just because the `CALL` within the `FOR`.  I would not do it within the same script.  I do not want to worry in second script about loop variables inside the first script.

Comment: As I said, they are limited to loop block scope. The only thing that `second.bat` inherits from its parent is the environment block.

Comment: @jwdonahue That's wromg. Loop blocks inherits all other FOR-variables from outer loop blocks, even when they are called

Comment: @jeb, Not quite. The outer scope is included in the inner scope, but the inner scope can hide the variable in the outer scope, as demonstrated by the example script I posted.

Answer (score 1):

But it's still safe to use the same name in a nested or called *sub* FOR loop.

The innermost variable is always the one which will be used.
FOR-Loop variables can't be changed and they don't modify the outer variables.

But there exits a glitch, each FOR-loop see ALL other currently active FOR-variables.

In your example, if you change your second.bat to

```
REM This is Second.bat
FOR %%X IN (1 2 3) DO (
  ECHO %%X
  echo %%A will also be shown
)
```

You will get also the values from the *caller* script.

This can be a bit annoying in a deep nested or library function.

Like

```
:myFunc
for /F %%x in ("myfile.txt") DO (
  set "line=%%x"
  call set new=%%line:~0,2%%
)
```

That block works until it's called from a construct like this

```
FOR %%l in (DUMMY-) do call :myFunc
```

Because the part `call set new=%%line:~0,2%%` has now a different meaning.
It's parsed to `call set new=DUMMY-ine:~0,2%%`